# How do figures work?

Tags: card-hunter

The Card Hunter [launch special](http://d2t0lbtko8zaws.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Launch-Special.jpg) includes, among other things, 9 extra figures. Is it possible to switch your characters' figures after they've been recruited? Or will I have to recruit a new character to use one of the new figures?

[image: Recruitment screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a new figure, simply drag it over your character portrait, as though it were simply an item you were equipping. You do not need to recruit a new character to get to use it.

Comment: I see now that if I would have gotten a bit further into the game before asking, I could have seen this for myself :-S.

Comment: Yeah, I figured (heh) you hadn't gotten far yet :P